# How to connect to two wireless networks with two adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-sharing

i'm in hotel with WiFi, and i need username + password to access the internet, and the server lock the user on the mac address of my laptop wireless adapter so i can't use the same user on my mobile.

i bought external wireless adapter and i was planing to share the internet over the new adapter by creating ad-hoc network, but i can't connect to two wireless network concurrently..

i tried to use connectify to share the internet over the new adapter .. and after i started hotspot i can see the network on my mobile but it never pass the "obtaining ip" level even if i entered a static IP.

my OS is Windows 7,
any ideas?

Comment: First thought is to talk to hotel staff to see if they'll allow you a second device.

Comment: i need to buy a new username and i'm planing to stay long time and that will cost me to much

Comment: What kind of phone?

Comment: Motorola Razr Xt-910 .. Android 4 ICS

Comment: If you're rooted you could look up Reverse Tethering options. Other than that I don't think I have the expertise to help in this scenario.

Comment: but that for sharing internet via USB .. i need wireless sharing